# Pandas - Map - Dummy Variables - Assign value of 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have two dataframes, `x.head()` looks like this:

```
top      mid       adc      support jungle
Irelia   Ahri      Jinx     Janna   RekSai
Gnar     Ahri      Caitlyn  Leona   Rengar
Renekton Fizz      Sivir    Annie   Rengar
Irelia   Leblanc   Sivir    Thresh  JarvanIV
Gnar     Lissandra Tristana Janna   JarvanIV
```

and dataframe `fullmatrix.head()` that I have created looks like this:

```
Irelia  Gnar    Renekton    Kassadin    Sion    Jax Lulu    Maokai  Rumble  Lissandra   ... XinZhao Amumu   Udyr    Ivern   Shaco   Skarner FiddleSticks    Aatrox  Volibear    MonkeyKing
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...
```

Now what I cannot figure out is how to assign a value of 1 for each name in the x dataframe to the respective column that has the same name in the `fullmatrix` dataframe row by row (both dataframes have the same number of rows).

Comment: throw us a bone here. simplify this sample dataset to about a 1/10 of what you have here and include your expected output (even if you have to calculate it manually).

Comment: Apologies Paul, the output should look like the second dataframe only with 1s where the name appears under the column for the respective row. Also I am still trying to figure out how to make my tables show up properly.

Irelia Gnar Ahri Renekton  Jinx   Kassadin    Janna   Sion     RekSai
1       0       1           0           1          0                1          0            1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this can be improved but one advantage is that it only requires the first DataFrame, and it's conceptually nice to chain operations until you get the desired solution.

```
fullmatrix = (x.stack()
               .reset_index(name='names')
               .pivot(index='level_0', columns='names', values='names')
               .applymap(lambda x: int(x!=None))
               .reset_index(drop=True))
```

note that only the names that appear in your `x` DataFrame will appear as columns in `fullmatrix`. if you want the additional columns you can simply perform a join.

Comment: I am getting: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. It works if I remove index='level_0'. Testing if it had assigned the values correctly.

Comment: It's unclear from your post what `x` has as an index as I'm assuming you have just printed the columns.. Could you either please print what your index is, or include the `reset_index(drop=True)` first. So it would look like `x.reset_index(drop=True).stack().....`

Comment: Legend. Just quickly tested as well and it's assigning the values the way it's supposed to. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: Awesome. One last thing on the index issue... if your index also contains names that you want counted (eg if your `top` col is actually the index) you can set `drop=False` in the first `reset_index` and then it will appear in the DataFrame when you stack it and then appear in the final count Frame.

Answer (score 2):

The OP tries to create a table of dummy variables with a set of data points. For each data point, it contains 5 attributes. There are in total `N` unique attributes.

We will use a simplied dataset to demonstrate how to do it:

- 5 unique attributes
- 3 data entries
- each data entry contains 3 attributes.

  ```
  x = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'],  
                    ['b', 'd', 'e'], 
                    ['e', 'b', 'a']])
  fullmatrix = pd.DataFrame([[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(3)], 
                            columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
  """ fullmatrix:
     a  b  c  d  e
  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  0  0  0  0
  2  0  0  0  0  0
  """

  # each row in x_temp is a string of attributed delimited by ","
  x_row_joined = pd.Series((",".join(row[1]) for row in x.iterrows()))    
  fullmatrix = x_row_joined.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
  ```

The method is inspired by [offbyone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2808975/offbyone)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889588/create-dummies-from-column-with-multiple-values-in-pandas/25208947#25208947) It uses [pandas.Series.str.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html). We first joins each row of x with a specified delimiter. Then make use of the `Series.str.get_dummies` method. The method takes a delimiter that we just use to join attributes and will generate the dummy-varaible table for you. (Caution: don't pick `sep` that exists in x.)

Comment: I tried the first solution and I am getting an output that looks like the way it is supposed to be but the 1s are in the wrong places

Comment: Maybe your `columns` has different order? @bloo Try to check the order of your columns in fullmatrix.

Comment: I am trying to debug the issue through my jupyter notebook and I am going to get back with whether this works. I want to use your first solution though cause it's easy, makes sense and other people can read and understand what's going on.

Comment: @bloo Tried to simply the answer. Hope this helps. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding a `key = 1` column and then iterating through each column for a list of pivoted dfs which you then horizontally merge with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html). Finally run a [`DataFrame.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update original *fullmatrix* with values from *pvt_df*, aligned to indices.

```
x['key'] = 1

dfs = []
for col in x.columns[:-1]:
    dfs.append(x.pivot_table(index=df.index, columns=[col], values='key').fillna(0))

pvt_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).astype(int)

fullmatrix.update(pvt_df)
fullmatrix = fullmatrix.astype(int)

fullmatrix   # ONLY FOR VISIBLE COLUMNS IN ORIGINAL POST
#    Irelia  Gnar  Renekton  Kassadin  Sion  Jax  Lulu  Maokai  Rumble  Lissandra  XinZhao  Amumu  Udyr  Ivern  Shaco  Skarner  FiddleSticks  Aatrox  Volibear  MonkeyKing
# 0       1     0         0         0     0    0     0       0       0          0        0      0     0      0      0        0             0       0         0           0
# 1       0     1         0         0     0    0     0       0       0          0        0      0     0      0      0        0             0       0         0           0
# 2       0     0         1         0     0    0     0       0       0          0        0      0     0      0      0        0             0       0         0           0
# 3       1     0         0         0     0    0     0       0       0          0        0      0     0      0      0        0             0       0         0           0
```

Comment: I am getting ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis at the fullmatrix.update(pvt_df), is index in (index=df.index, columns=[col], values='key') supposed to be =dfs.index or something else?